# ValueError: Invalid tensors 'input' were found

Tags: android, python, tensorflow, tensorboard, tensorflow-datasets

I'm not able to convert .pb to tflite

Here is the command that I'm executing to generate .pb I am successful in generating it.

```
IMAGE_SIZE=224
ARCHITECTURE="mobilenet_1_1.0_${IMAGE_SIZE}"

python retrain.py  
 --bottleneck_dir=tf_files/bottlenecks   
 --how_many_training_steps=500   
 --model_dir=tf_files/models/   
 --summaries_dir=tf_files/training_summaries/"${ARCHITECTURE}"  
  --output_graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb   
  --output_labels=tf_files/retrained_labels.txt   
  --architecture="${ARCHITECTURE}"  
  --image_dir=tf_files/flower_photos
```

Once I am trying to create that .pb to .tflite get fail with same error `"ValueError: Invalid tensors 'input' were found."`

```
tflite_convert \
  --output_file=foo.tflite \
  --graph_def_file=retrained_graph.pb \
  --input_arrays=input \
  --output_arrays=MobilenetV1/Predictions/Reshape_1
```

Comment: What is the `input` tensor? Can you post the code which defines it?

Comment: I don't have code for it. i am using terminal base converter. https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/cmdline_examples

Comment: @AmitPrajapati Found any solution for this?

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar yes, i try with difference way, its working fine. i will post answer soon.

Answer (score 2):

I just follow this google code demo.

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#0

**Working fine**

```
IMAGE_SIZE=224
ARCHITECTURE="mobilenet_1.0_${IMAGE_SIZE}"

python -m scripts.retrain \
--bottleneck_dir=tf_files/bottlenecks \
--how_many_training_steps=500 \
--model_dir=tf_files/models/ \
--summaries_dir=tf_files/training_summaries/"${ARCHITECTURE}" \
--output_graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb \
--output_labels=tf_files/retrained_labels.txt \
--architecture="${ARCHITECTURE}" \
--image_dir=tf_files/flower_photos

tflite_convert   --graph_def_file=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb   --output_file=tf_files/optimized_graph.tflite   --input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF   --output_format=TFLITE   --input_shape=1,224,224,3   --input_array=input   --output_array=final_result   --inference_type=FLOAT   --input_data_type=FLOAT
```

I made one change for it simpley change mobilenet version.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error as you with tflite converter python api.

This caused by the params we passed in input_arrays.

`input_arrays` need `tensor_name` defined in `tf.placeholder(name="input")` **not** `proto map key string` defined in `build_signature_def(inputs={"input": tensor_info_proto},outputs...)`.

Here is a simple example.

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None], name="input_x")
...

builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(saved_model_path)
input_tensor_info = {"input": tf.saved_model.build_tensor_info(x)}
output_tensor_info = ...
signature_def = tf.saved_model.build_signature_def(inputs=input_tensor_info,
                                                   outputs=...,
                                                   method_name=...)
builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(...)
builder.save()

# convert saved_model to tflite format.
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_path,
                                                     input_arrays=["input"],
                                                     ...)
...
...
```

Once you run a code like this will raise an error `"ValueError: Invalid tensors 'input' were found."`

If we make a small change as bellow, it will succeed.

```
# a small change when convert
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_path,
                                                     input_arrays=["input_x"],
                                                     ...)
```